# For loop only gives me last value of the array and append gives me all the values of the array

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I'm trying to make a search movie app that when I enter the value on the input box it gives me all the containers containing title, images and rates. now I'm trying to give the titles the values of the API array when I click the button to search the movies.

I'm stuck because when I loop the array it gives me only the last value and when I try to append it gives me all the values.

```js
const moviesCtn = document.querySelectorAll('.jsMovieFlex');
const input = document.querySelector('#inpText');
const button = document.querySelector('#btn');


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inpValue = input.value;
  moviesCtn.forEach(ctn => {
    ctn.style.display = 'flex';
  })
  searchMovie(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${inpValue}`);
})


const searchMovie = async(url) => {
  const moviesImage = document.querySelectorAll('.jsMovieImage');
  const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title-movie');
  const rates = document.querySelectorAll('h3');
  const req = await fetch(url);
  const data = await req.json();
  console.log(data);
  const arrayNames = data.map(names => names.show.name);
  console.log(arrayNames);
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
    const names = arrayNames[i];
    console.log(names);
    titles.forEach(title => {
      title.append(names);
    })
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #151c3f;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(avengers-endgame-locandina-Sentieri.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate(-0.6%, -2%);
}

.main h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main>input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 5px #00000096;
}

.main>button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-80%, 200%);
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  inset: 0;
  background: #0000006e;
}

.movie-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.movie-container>h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-30%);
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
}

.movie-container>h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2%;
}

.movie-container>.movie-image {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Search Movie App</h1>
  <input type="text" id="inpText" placeholder="Search Movie">
  <button id="btn">Click Here</button>
</div>

<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
<div class="movie-container jsMovieFlex">
  <h1 class="title-movie"></h1>
  <div class="movie-image jsMovieImage"></div>
  <h3>rate</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: please cut down the code and provide it as a [repro] (`Ctrl + M` or `<>` button) - take extra attention to the word **minimal**!

Comment: can't i put the code on codepen?

Comment: I'm not sure the "when i loop the array it gives me only the last value" part of the question makes much sense. For "when i try to append it gives me all the values": `titles.forEach(title =>  { title.append(names); })` loops through every movie container and appends every name. You might have more luck with `titles[i].append(names);` instead of this forEach loop to populate these values. A better approach though might be to create the movie containers as you need them rather than trying to populate pre-existing ones.

Comment: No, read the linked guideline. A codepen may be used as an extension but never as a replacement to debugging details as listed in the link

Comment: @BenStephens its unclear to me too. 1 ) - - does he want to loop through all the options and pick one then display the one to the user, 2 ) - - or he wants to display all the options to the user and let them pick one?

Comment: i want each title to have the specific value of the array (for example the first value of the array goes on the first title that is in the first movie container and like that even the second value, third ecc ecc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `for`, where you go through the names and assign it to all titles, which means the last name will be on all titles:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
    const name = arrayNames[i];
    titles.forEach(title => {
      title.append(name); // <------- each title gets current name
    })
  }
```

But you just want to assign it to the title at index `i`:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
    const name = arrayNames[i];
    titles[i].append(name)
  }
```

My guess is that you got confused with the naming (I did), because it is quite obvious otherwise. It might help to use more declarative variable names, particularly ones that are distinctive (i.e. avoid using synonyms next to each other, like "title" and "name"):

```
  for (let i = 0; i < movieNames.length; i++) {
    const movieName = movieNames[i];
    titleTags[i].append(movieName)
  }
```

Comment: it worked, thanks man i'll be more careful.

Comment: That's great! If you found the answer helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer and/or voting for it